# SBS2008 Certificate problems

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-sbs

The sbs2008 certificates are driving me crazy.
Can somebody tell me how to completely disable them ?

For example I have problems with the certificate source, name etc when using RemoteApp or trying to use Outlook Exchange OWA.

I don't care about the certifcates and it would make my whole life a lot easier if I was able to just delete them !

Thanks.

Comment: What certificates are you talking about exactly?  If you remove certificates that will only cause more problems.

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT TRY TO DELETE THE CERTIFICATES!**

You will cause more problems than you 'fix' if you succeed. HTTPS will break for one. I'd be surprised if RemoteApp worked at all. The problem isn't *caused* by certificates at all, it's squawking because you're using a *self-signed* certificate. Certificates are meant to essentially verify identity (among other things, but I'll be brief). Your system currently has no way to prove its identity via a reliable source, so it generates its own self-signed certificate.

What you can do is add the self-signed certificate to the machines you're working with. Take a look at [this TechNet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx). You can also do this [via GPO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770315(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I mean disabling the need to check for a certifcate.

Comment: I don't want the client to check it and the server to serve it. I want to disable all this certifcate crap, it's so unusefull for us. And yes I did try to import it manually. And it's showing in trusted root certifcates however the error is still appearing.